# Is it possible to pass function returned value as form value from html to views?

Tags: python, django

I have JS function which returns array of items. I would like to pass it via form to views. At this moment this array is being passed as ajax request but it is not too much reliable. It works but sometimes sends the empty request. Below i put the code to show what I would like to obtain. The js function is kinda dummy because the code is quite long but the role of this function is just to return the array. Is the below logic correct to make it working  ?

```
<form method='post' action='/category/' class="form-inline">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <button class="nav-link purple darken-4" type="submit" 
                    name="Array" value=test() style="background-color: 
                    grey;">Make order</button>
                  </li>

    </form>

    <script>
    function test(){
      var array = []
      return aray
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to send data via ajax, you have to populate your form with hidden inputs before submitting.

Modify your javascript:

```js
function test() {
    return ['1', '2']
}

const form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
form.onsubmit = function (e) {
    const elems = test();
    elems.forEach((el) => {
        const input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        input.setAttribute("name", "test[]");
        input.setAttribute("value", el);
        form.appendChild(input);
    })
}
```

and you can read your form data from request using `request.POST.getlist('test[]')`